# How can I prove this function equation

Tags: functions

let $g:[a,b]\longrightarrow [0,1]$ and $g$ is one to one and is increasing,prove that
there exists a funcition $f$,such that
$$g(x)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{f(b)-f(a)},x\in (a,b)$$,where $f$ is one to one.

Thank you everyone can help me.

Comment: one-to-ome *and* onto?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, $f$ is not required to be continuous and the expression for $g$ only has to hold in the open interval $(a,b)$. So the 'obvious' problem doesn't occur, does it?

Comment: But maybe my comment only suggests that there _is_ some assumption missing. Otherwise choose $f(b)=1$, $f(a)=0$, $f(x)=g(x)$ everywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an obvious solution that works (as long as there are no constraints missing in the problem statement). Let $f\colon[a,b]\to[0,1]$ be given by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x=a,\\1&\text{if }x=b,\\g(x)&\text{if }a<x<b.\end{cases}$$
Then for $a<x<b$ we have $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{f(b)-f(a)}=\frac{g(x)-0}{1-0}=g(x)$$
as required.

Moreover, $f$ is strictly increasing:
If $x<b$ then $f(x)\le g(x)$ as it trivially holds both for $x=a$ and for $a<x<b$.
If $x>a$ then $f(x)\ge g(x)$ as it trivially holds both for $x=b$ and for $a<x<b$.
Therefore, if $x<y$ then $x<b$ and $y>a$, hence
$$f(x)\le g(x)<g(y)\le f(y).$$
Especially, $f$ is one-to-one.